# Log in android development

Tags: android

I am using `android.util.Log`for logging purposes in my Android application. In short my code is as

```
import android.util.Log;
...
private static final String TAG = "myActivity"; // Creating a tag 
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
          Log.i(TAG,"My INFO_msg should be print ");
}
```

The problem is that, when my application runs, this LOG message doesn't appear on the console window. Is it printed on another window ? If my work is to print LOG messages on console window then what will be the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it in the LogCat window (Window > Show view > Other, Android > Logcat)