# Android Eclipse Logcat messages: How does ADT get the Application column?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I ran Logcat on a command window and tried all possible formats:

**brief** — Display priority/tag and PID of the process issuing the message (the default format).

**process** — Display PID only.

**tag** — Display the priority/tag only.

**raw** — Display the raw log message, with no other metadata fields.

**time** — Display the date, invocation time, priority/tag, and PID of the process.

**thread** — Display the priority, tag, and the PID and TID.

**threadtime** — Display the date, invocation time, priority, tag, and the PID and TID.

**long** — Display all metadata fields and separate messages with blank lines.

I could not find in any of those formats **how does Eclipse ADT's Logcat figure out what is the name of the Application issuing the message**.

If you use Eclipse, look at the LogCat tab, it has *Time, PID, Application, Tag* and *Text* columns.
Does it use the TID to identify the application? Where can I get the list of TIDs and app names running in the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had about the same question on:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366709/android-using-logcat-in-the-command-line-application-info-exact-priority-f

i'm not sure how it works on eclipse , but you can have a workaround: take from the log which process id was started that matches the package name . 
the weird thing is that this might be the same way it works there , since for some log messages , eclipse doesn't show which application has written the log message.
you might also be able to fetch the package name by pid , but i can't find out the method to do this.

Comment: I saw it, **>> adb shell ps [pid]**.    It shows all required info

Comment: It means that if I am making my own LogCat, I have to run one extra command for each log message received, to check it's pid. Because I cannot assume the pid existed when adb logcat was launched.

Comment: do you know by any chance of a java function to fetch the package name by giving the pid as a parameter? that could help a lot.

Comment: maybe this can help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542326/android-how-to-get-the-processname-or-packagename-by-using-pid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542326/android-how-to-get-the-processname-or-packagename-by-using-pid)

Comment: i see. this could be useful . thanks. wonder if there is a shorter way.