# Customize LogCat Columns in Eclipse ADT

Tags: adt, android-logcat

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10565001) suggests that it's possible to customize LogCat Columns from the command line.

Is it possible to do the same for the DDMS view in Eclipse?

**Update:** I am looking at `ANDROID_LOG_TAGS` env var. It looks [promising](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#filteringOutput).

Comment: One quick solution that I use for removing unwanted columns is to shrink the size of a column until it disappears.