# Linux command to find application label using PID.

Tags: android, linux

I have all PID. I want to find the exact application name from this pid.
Let, a PID = 3355.its package = com.xxxx.yyyyy.actual app name = Mail
i dont need the com.xxxx.yyyyy, i need Mail using PID.
Thanks

Comment: You can use this code get the process name from process ID http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542326/android-how-to-get-the-processname-or-packagename-by-using-pid/8543401#8543401 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841161/get-application-name-from-package-name Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get process detail including environment, commandline ...  from the procfs

for example:

```
cat /proc/3355/cmdline
```

Comment: thanks :). But, say for gmail cat "/proc/3355/cmdline" command still return like com.google.android.gsf.login. We need the name of App "Gmail".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with -

```
 ps aux | grep 3355
```

Comment: root@android:/ # ps aux | grep 3770
/system/bin/sh: grep: not found