# How to get app package name by pid?

Tags: android

```
String callerPackage = getAppNameByPID(getContext(), Binder.getCallingPid());
private String getAppNameByPID(Context context, int callingPid) {
//How ?
    ....

    }
```

my questions:
How to get app package name by pid?

Comment: Here is discussion you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542326/android-how-to-get-the-processname-or-packagename-by-using-pid

Answer (score 2):

Each process can hold multiple packages, so it looks like:

```
private String[] getPackageNames(int pid)
{
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getContext().getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : runningAppProcesses) 
    {
        try 
        { 
            if(runningAppProcessInfo.pid == pid)
            {
                return runningAppProcessInfo.pkgList;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```