# How to start a process on Android device using adb

Tags: android, adb

I am using adb commands to manage processes on android phone.

I am able to kill a specific process by the command

```
adb kill "PID"  (PID is the process ID)
```

and the process gets killed.

But when I start it using the command

```
adb start "PID"
```

It doesnt start the process.

And the process that I wish to start is in /system/bin folder and I dont know what the package or activity name is of that process. All I know is "PID" and "User" of the process.

Is there any command that starts a specific process on android device?

Comment: is this a native or dalvik app? can you give the actual name?

Comment: this app is in /system/bin folder and this is a native app.

Answer (score 3):

Once you've killed the process corresponding to `PID`, how can you start it again?

You can instead try to launch an app from `adb` this way:-

```
adb shell
am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

Or you can use this directly:

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

Comment: The process that I am going to start is in /system/bin folder and I dont know the package name for that..
All I know is PID and user for that process

Comment: you can get the running app info using a `PID` [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8543401/2024761) way. After that, you can do what I suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

Native apps do not have activities. They are just that - native binaries.

If all you know is process' numeric ID - then `ps <PID>` command will show you the process binary's name in the `NAME` column. Like this:

```
# ps 407
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
root      407   1     4540   272   ffffffff 000160a4 S /sbin/adbd
```

If `PPID` value is `1` - it means that it has been started by system `init` and more likely than not the app is a "service" app. To control it you need to find the service's name and then just use `stop <service>` and `start <service>`.

To find the service's name run `grep ^service /init*rc | grep <binary name>` the service's name will be in the second column (i.e. "adbd"):

```
# grep ^service /init*rc | grep /sbin/adbd
/init.rc:service adbd /sbin/adbd
```

So to properly control this app - you should use `stop adbd` and `start adbd`.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you knew your binary is in /system/bin so I assume that you also know name of that binary file.
In case you don't, that command will help you find out:

```
ps PID
```

To start a binaries (eg. uptime) you just have to type its name in shell:

```
adb shell
uptime
```

or in one command

```
adb shell uptime
```

but if your binary file isn't in one of the directories listed in $PATH you have to type whole path to it

```
adb shell /system/bin/uptime
```

you can check $PATH with:

```
adb shell echo $PATH
```