# Get all logs from specific PID in android/linux?

Tags: android, c, linux, logging

see currently in android there is one utility called logcat which shows all user space programs's log on stdout or terminal.

but here I do not want all messages in list. But i want to see only specific application's log only.

So if i need to make such utility then how can i do that?

see if i want all log from pid 132 and 324 then i will run as follows on terminal

```
logcat_special 132 324
```

and now it will show all messgaes from that pid.

If this things are hard to implemet with pid then we can  go with application name
as

```
logcat_special vlc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log cat already has a package  based filter . take a look here : [Logcat options](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)
also according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8543401/951448) answer you can find app package from its pid.

So combining that with logcat you can achieve the functionality you are after.

This option should work:

```
logcat <your package name>:<log level>
```

for example `logcat android.test:V`

Comment: I coudnt find package base filter option i can go with tag based option adb logcat ActivityManager:I MyApp:D *:S