# Identifying the process on which my code runs

Tags: android

Is there a way to know which process my code is running on?

My app has two processes, one is the main process, the other process is used by an external SDK.
My custom application object is sometimes called from the other process.
I want to know which process is calling the application object.
Is it possible?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8543401/2719186

Comment: Thank you, but I need to know what is the current pid my code runs on.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html

Comment: sorry, buy i don't see how any of the functions there could help. could you elaborate?

Comment: Either of these methods would allow you to identify the process, one by name, the other by a process ID. What exactly do you need if these aren't what you want?

Comment: I want to identify the process that i am on, in my case it could be one of these two, com.example.app or com.example.app:remote. I want to know which of them has called the current class(MyApp.class), since both of them can run this class.